# Redirect HTTP GET method to a different url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get

I know this question is very basic but if someone could help me here, I would be very grateful.

I am trying to redirect all requests to http://example.com/index.php?/api/function to http://anotherexample.com/api/function using htaccess

I have been doing some research and all I find are redirect with the POST method but nothing really explained with GET.

I have tried:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php?/api/function http://anotherexample.com/api/function [NC,L,R=301]
```

this gives me no success.
Thanks in advance

Comment: RewriteRules only work on the path component of a URL, not on the query string. If you want to evaluate the query string as well, use a RewriteCond before your RewriteRule. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the code above:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/api/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php http://anotherexample.com/api/%1? [QSA,L]
```

thanks for the tip CBroe